# Is there any alternative to creating one fixture per variable in a py.test class?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I would like to use some common data in all my py.test class methods, and only in that class, e.g.

```py
n_files = 1000
n_classes = 10
n_file_per_class = int(n_files / n_classes)
```

I found out that I can use fixtures, e.g.:

```py
class TestDatasplit:

    @pytest.fixture()
    def n_files(self):
        return 1000

    @pytest.fixture()
    def n_classes(self):
        return 10

    @pytest.fixture()
    def n_files_per_class(self, n_files, n_classes):
        return int(n_files / n_classes)

    def test_datasplit_1(self, n_files):
        assert n_files == 1000

    def test_datasplit(self, n_files_per_class):
        assert n_files_per_class == 100
```

but here I need to create a fixture for all my variables, but that seems quite verbose (I have much more than 3 variables)...

What is the best way to create a bunch of shared variables in a py.test class?

Comment: Are these tests even discovered by `py.test` if they're wrapped in a class that doesn't derive from `unittest.TestCase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what @das-g said, but if you wanted to use fixtures, then you could have a fixture which returns a object based on a custom class, or e.g. a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: That is what I will probably end up with if I have no other option.

Answer (score 9):

Your tests don't seem to be mutating these values, so you can use module-level or class-level constants. Pytest fixtures are there to provide each test with a separate copy of a value, so that tests don't begin to depend on each other (or inadvertently make each other fail) when one or more test mutate the values.

Comment: What if my tests mutate the values?

Comment: If your tests _do_ mutate the values, stay with fixtures, so that each test gets a fresh copy of the original value instead of a value that has potentially been modified by another test. And, if your tests rely on the modifications made by other tests, you should really, _really_, __really__ rethink your testing approach.